# Reading from Global Temp Table With Oracle.ManagedDataAccess

Tags: c#, oracle

We're using a stored procedure which involves multiple global temporary tables and PL SQL arrays in an effort to avoid using dynamic SQL queries and due to the large number of records we might be returning. However, we're running into a bit of a problem when we attempt to read from the result.

Our pattern in the past has been to read from the result using code like the following:

```
DataTable result = new DataTable();
const string procName = "some proc";
using (var connection = new OracleConnection("some connection string"))
using (var command = new OracleCommand(procName, connection))
{
   command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   command.BindByName = true;
   command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("my_ref_cursor", OracleDbType.RefCursor)
   {
      Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
   });
   connection.Open();
   using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
   {
     while (reader.Read())
     {
         // some logic here
     }
   }
   connection.Close();
}
```

However, when we try to read back the results from the reader, it skips over the parsing loop as if there is no data. When we replicate the call in TOAD, we get back results without any problems.

We've guessed that the driver is performing a commit while we're attempting to read back the results, but we're not certain how to get around this. We've tried using the following:

```
connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted);
```

But that throws a lovely exception, which, while explicit, doesn't help me actually solve the problem.

```
System.ArgumentException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147024809
  Message=IsolationLevel must be ReadCommitted or Serializable
Parameter name: isolationLevel
  Source=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess
  ParamName=isolationLevel
  StackTrace:
       at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)
```

Any thoughts on whether or not we can do what we're trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the error message, isolation level `IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted` is not allowed. You must use `ReadCommitted` (the default) or `Serializable`.

Did you create the global temporary table with `ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS` (the default)?

Try to create the table with

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE ....
(
...
)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
```

Comment: This works great as long as you remember to truncate the table at the start of the next operation

Comment: I've passed this along to our DBA; hoping to be able to accept your solution!

Comment: Yep - we've had problems with ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS via Managed Data Access no matter how we tried to change the session settings and had to switch to ON COMMIT PRESERVE and doing TRUNCATE/INSERT/COMMIT in an autonomous transaction rather than just INSERTS to get it to work.